# SwiftUI iPad app opening full screen (as expected) on preview, but in simulator opens minimised in the sidebar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad, swiftui

Expected behaviour (and it works this way in the preview): https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLuQY.png

Actual behaviour (in the simulator):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKaAR.jpg

Unfortunately, I do not have a physical device to test it out on at this time.

I've updated the code below to include the 'magic' as maybe I've screwed something up in there. The LoginView and RegisterView are similar (vstack in a zstack) but with text/secure fields for username/password.

```
import SwiftUI


import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack{
                Color(K.BrandContent.onyx)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack(spacing: 0.0) {
                    Spacer()
                    Image(K.BrandContent.logo)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 1000, alignment: .center)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    Text(K.BrandContent.name)
                        .font(.system(size: 70))
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(K.BrandContent.red))
                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink(destination: LoginView()) {
                        Text("Login")
                            .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold))
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                    .background(Color(K.BrandContent.white))
                    .padding(.vertical)
                    .containerShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25))
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: RegisterView()) {
                        Text("Register")
                            .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold))
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                    .background(Color(K.BrandContent.white))
                    .padding(.vertical)
                    .containerShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25))
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
        //.previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: K.Devices.ipad))
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: K.Devices.ipad))
    }
}
```

Comment: How about trying to comment out/delete the .previewDevice line? It should be the only difference between the simulator and the preview.

Comment: @DevB2F I did so, and it doesn't change anything. Same actual vs expected behaviours :(

Comment: Get rid of the NavigationView

Comment: @loremipsum Making that change gives the same behaviour.

Comment: Make sure you don’t have any other navigation views. Most apps only need one and NavigationStack is the newer better option. Tab views and sheets are exceptions.

Comment: @loremipsum I had NavigationViews in the other swiftUI views, but I've since removed them - and still have the same behaviour. Just in case I'm screwing something up, I've updated the original code above and included the 'magic'

Comment: This only happens with NavigationViews or NavigationSplitViews. If it is still happening you have more you have to find them and remove them leave only one NavigationStack at the top.

Comment: @loremipsum That was it - I had a brain fart and was woking inside a specific view .swift file, not realizing that I was also inside the app .swift file as well :P

Comment: @stygarfield glad to help. If you don’t mind can you accept the answer by clicking the green check mark and maybe upvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Double Column setup only happens with

```
NavigationView
```

Or

```
NavigationSplitView
```

If your intended navigation setup is `stack`.

You should remove all other setups and leave only a single `NavigationStack` at the very top of the app.